# <a href> direct to page and start function

Tags: javascript

I have a problem. I got an a href linked to an other page (I'll call it page 2) of my web app. If the user click this link it should direct him to this site and should start a function which is defined in a globale .js file. This function scrolls to a certain div and looks like

```
const div4 = document.getElementById('div4');

    let scrollToDiv4 = () => {
        div4.scrollIntoView();
    }
```

Now I got the linked `<div id="div4">` in page 2. In page 1 is the a href, linking to page 2 and starting the function `<a href="/page2.html" onclick="scrollToDiv4()">`.

But the function isn't executing, how do I do this?

Comment: You have added `scrollToDiv4()` in the script somewhere?

Comment: yes its defined inside global script.js file and also inside the navigation and its working

Comment: why don't you use `href="page2.html#div4"`

Comment: oh okay, thats the answer of my question :D thank! Didint know this works

Comment: @dev you beat me, you were writing comment, and I was writing answer :)

Comment: @Kenny haha hope you all are doing good

Answer (score 1):

No need to write scroll function.

Wrap your container (which you want to be displayed after scroll) in `<a>` tag and give id to it

Like

```
<a id="divscroll">
   // Your div which has to be displayed
</a>
```

Now in first page

Use

```
<a href="/page2.htm#divscroll">
```

More on this

https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000049.htm

Answer (score 1):

You could track that the button was clicked using cache? or cookie then redirect the user to the page after that. Then when you are on the desired page. check if the cookie has value. But this is quite **complicated**

or if you are simply redirecting the user to a certain section in the 2nd page using the link. I think it's better to do this

```
<a href="/page2.html#div4"></a>
```

To make the page scroll smoothly you could add css

```
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

Here's a good example from w3schools => https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_smooth_scroll.asp#section2

Answer (score 0):

You already have what you need, with a minor syntax change:

```
    <a href="www.mysite.com" onclick="return theFunction();">Item</a>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function theFunction () {
            // return true or false, depending on whether you want to allow the `href` property to follow through or not
        }

</script>
T
```

he default behavior of the  tag's onclick and href properties is to execute the onclick, then follow the href as long as the onclick doesn't return false, canceling the event (or the event hasn't been prevented)

And also this works `<a href="/page2.htm#divscroll">`